# Two overflow lines on hot water heater

Tags: water-heater

Why do I have two overflow lines plumbed from my hot water heater. I know what the one is for the pressure relief valve, but I have another one plumber directly after the shutoff valve on the cold water inlet. This one drains all the time outside and I am not sure why. It is not necessarily hot water coming from it as it is backing up in the cold water inlet. I have not been able to find any information on why the second overflow line would be plumbed and why it runs continuously.

Thank you for your feedback

Comment: What kind of hot water heater is this? is the second line "running all of the time" a condensate drain? Can you share the make and model of heater and the fuel source?

Comment: Does your water heater have a thermal expansion tank? This would be installed on the cold water inlet after the shutoff valve.

Comment: it is an electric water heater. Yes, the overflow line that is plumbed directly after the shut off valve runs water outside all the time. It is plumbed as a small water line, not like the overflow PVC line for the pressure relief valve. It actually comes out of the side of the house with the overflow PVC line.

Comment: I do not have an expansion tank installed

Comment: I kind of took it as this line might act as an expansion tank.

Comment: Can you take some pictures?

Comment: I agree on pictures, what you’re describing sounds like it has no purpose.

Comment: ... might it be a malfunctioning backflow preventer?